# How to add IP address to a Cosmosdb database firewall through the Azure CLI

Tags: azure, shell, azure-cosmosdb

I want to add my IP to the cosmosdb firewall through the Azure CLI.
The only way to do it with the Azure CLI is with [`az cosmosdb update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_update), but it overrides the current IPs in the firewall.

I'm using MacOS so I can get my IP through `curl ifconfig.me`.

How can I add my IP to the firewall without overriding the current IPs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply GET the list with [`az cosmosdb list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_list) and append your IP to a list, and `cosmosdb update` with that list:

```
DESIRED_IP=$(curl ifconfig.me)
CURRENT_IPS=$(az cosmosdb list | jq -r '.[0].ipRules | .[] | .ipAddressOrRange' | paste -sd "," -)
DESIRED_IPS=$CURRENT_IPS,$DESIRED_IP
az cosmosdb update -n .. -g .. --ip-range-filter "$DESIRED_IPS"
```

Comment: Warning: using `az cosmosdb list` will get the ipRules for all cosmosdb accounts. If you want to get them for just one, use `az cosmosdb show -n ... -g ...  | jq -r '.ipRules[].ipAddressOrRange' | paste -sd "," -`

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply add a new IP (like with most azure services ), you need to get the current IP list, add the new one to the end, then update the whole list.

`az cosmosdb list` gets a json object that contains all the info about ALL your cosmos db instances.

The trick is to use querying (`--query`) to extract the IP list from the json for just  the db instance you want to update.

Here is a sample script:

```
# Your IP
$IP_ADDRESS="1.2.3.4"
# Get current cosmos IP rules
CURRENT_IPS=$(az cosmosdb list --query "[?instanceId=='my-istance-guid-here'].ipRules[].ipAddressOrRange | join(',',@)"  | sed 's/"//g')
# Add new IP to the exisintg listb (stupid cosmos has different system to everything else - cant justy add a new IP)
DESIRED_IPS=$CURRENT_IPS,$IP_ADDRESS
# Add the IP address to the Cosmos DB firewall using the Azure CLI
az cosmosdb update --name "my-cosmos-db-name-here" --resource-group "my-resource-group" --ip-range-filter "$DESIRED_IPS"
```

More info on az command here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-list

Morei info on --query / JMESPath here - https://jmespath.org